# C# FileInfo - additional conditions in this LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, fileinfo

I am attempting to create a method in this class which, when called, will scan all subfolders of the Documents folder, find any subfolders called "Log", and within those Log folders, find any files that are of .log extension, and have been created or modified in the last 24 hours.  This what I have so far. Assume that the `string path` argument passed in to the method is C:\Users\Me\Documents:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace FileFinder
{
    class ModifiedFileFinder
    {
        static public IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetFilesModifiedInLast24Hours(string path)
        {
            var directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            DateTime from_date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            DateTime to_date = DateTime.Now;
            var files = directory.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
              .Where(file => file.LastWriteTime >= from_date && file.LastWriteTime <= to_date);
            return files.ToList();    
        }
    }
}
```

I believe I have the "Last 24 hours" requirement handled, but what I'm struggling with is how to indicate that I only want the `GetFiles` method to look in subfolders called Log, and only for files with .txt extension.

**EDIT #1:**

With help from the comment below from @Jimi I am closer, but just seem to be missing one step.  Here's the is the updated code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace CGLogFiles
{
    class ModifiedFileFinder
    {
        static public IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetFilesModifiedInLast24Hours(string path)
        {
            var directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            DateTime from_date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            DateTime to_date = DateTime.Now;
            var files = directory.EnumerateFiles("*.log", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
              .Where(file => file.Directory.Name.Equals("Log") && file.LastWriteTime >= from_date && file.LastWriteTime <= to_date);

            return files.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem now is that the method definitely is not looking in the subdirectories, despite the `SearchOption.AllDirectories` argument.  It is only returning files from the top level directory.  Any ideas on that?

Comment: You can add a condition: `file.Directory.Name.Equals("Log")`. The filter is specified in `GetFiles("*.txt", ...)`. You should probably use `EnumerateFiles()` and `yield return...`. Or `EnumerateDirectories()` first, then the content. --- IMO, `&& file.LastWriteTime <= to_date` is not required.

Comment: Thanks @Jimi.  I'm much closer now, but still seem to be missing one thing - please see my Edit #1 in my post.

Comment: `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles()` wants, as first argument, the filter of the files type to include; so, since you want to find `.txt` files, then `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`. -- Note that `SearchOption.AllDirectories` can be *dangerous*: it could take forever to enumerate the directory tree. Use it only when you're ~sure that the path won't contain reparse points and such (so you won't ever us it in `AppData`, or the current User main folder etc.)

Comment: @Jimi Is there a less dangerous way to search subdirectories?

Comment: Your snippet shows you are searching `*.log` but in your description it's `*.txt`.

Comment: @Jimi, sorry, to clarify, I actually am now looking for files with .log extension, not .txt.  So the above code from Edit 1 is reflecting that.  Given that, any idea why it's not searching in subdirectories?

Comment: @vendettamit sorry for the confusion.  .log extension is the correct extension.  Post updated.

Comment: It does. That code looks for files that have a `.log` extension where the direct parent folder name is `Log`: e.g. `C:\Users\Me\Documents\Log\somefile.log`, `C:\Users\Me\Documents\SomeFolder\Log\someOtherFile.log` etc. If this is not the directory structure you're looking for, post some examples.

Comment: @Jimi for whatever reason, it's only finding my test file from your first example `C:\Users\Me\Documents\Log\somefile.log` , but not anything the next level down, like your second example `C:\Users\Me\Documents\SomeFolder\Log\someOtherFile.log`. I've placed a breakpoint and have verified that the `files` variable contains only the file from the first example.  I'm sure it's user error as it sounds like you've tested it on your side.  I'll keep digging here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this procedure will look into the directory tree that way. See that there's an *agreement* on the folder structure that should be searched. E.g., it won't find `C:\Users\Me\Documents\SomeFolder\Log\Other\someOtherFile.log`.

Comment: @Jimi definitely agreed on the folder structure.  The example you've just posted is not one of the cases.  All cases fall into the two examples you posted above.

Comment: All right. Have you also considered the case? `Log`, `log` and `LOG` are different, you're looking for just `Log`. If the Directory name can have a different case, use `file.Directory.Name.Equals("LOG", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` instead. The file extension is case insensitive.

Comment: @Jimi so now I've completely removed the `file.Directory.Name.Equals("Log")` condition to try and further diagnose, and still having the issue.  It looks like it's not going beyond one level down for searching subfolders.  For example:  `C:\Users\Me\Documents\somefile.log` gets returned.  `C:\Users\Me\Documents\Log\somefile.log` gets returned.  `C:\Users\Me\Documents\Somefolder\Log\somefile.log` does NOT get returned.  And that's regardless of whether I'm using `file.Directory.Name.Equals("Log")` or not.

Comment: Well, that's not the method. Check the file time (the `Modified` property in the file property panel, not the `Created` time). Or just remove the DateTime check.

Comment: @Jimi great idea to remove the DateTime check:  Sure enough, it works without the DateTime check.  So then what is wrong with my DateTime check?  Clearly the `LastWriteTime` property is not the one I should be using.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe is `.CreationTime || .LastWriteTime` or `.CreationTimeUtc || .LastWriteTimeUtc`. I cannot tell you what you're looking for :)

Comment: `CreationTime` may give me what I need.  Testing it now.

Comment: `CreationTime` gets me 90% of the way there.  I will be running this program once every 24 hours - at the time the program runs, if a new log file has been created but is still being written to, it's going to grab the incomplete file.  This would be fine if we were going to get the complete file 24 hours later on the next run, but we won't since the creation time for that file will be greater than 24 hours ago.  Adding `|| .LastWriteTime` as you've suggested seems like it would solve that, but this code is clearly not honoring `LastWriteTime` in all my tests so far.

Comment: Sounds like you need to check and skip any files open for writing. Testing against `DateTime.Now` seem unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursivity to find all subfolders named "Log"

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string path = @"C:\Logs\Test";

        var files = GetFilesModifiedInLast24Hours(path);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Method: GetFilesModifiedInLast24Hours

```
    public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetFilesModifiedInLast24Hours(string path)
    {

        var toDate = DateTime.Now;
        var fromDate = toDate.AddDays(-1);

        var fileInfos = new List<FileInfo>();

        var directoryPaths = GetFolders(path);

        const string fileExtension = "*.txt";
        foreach (var directoryPath in directoryPaths)
        {
            var directory = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
            
            var files = directory.GetFiles(fileExtension)
                .Where(file => file.LastWriteTime >= fromDate && file.LastWriteTime <= toDate)
                .ToList();

            if (files.Any())
            {
                fileInfos.AddRange(files);
            }
        }


        return fileInfos;
    }
```

Recursive function to find all subfolders named "Log"

```
   private static List<string> GetFolders(string folderPath)
    {
        const string folderToFind = "Log";

        var folders = new List<string>();
        var paths = Directory.GetDirectories(folderPath);

        foreach (var path in paths)
        {
            var directoryName = new DirectoryInfo(path).Name;
            if (directoryName == folderToFind)
            {
                folders.Add(path);
            }

            if (!IsDirectoryEmpty(path))
            {
                var subDirectory = GetFolders(path);
                if (subDirectory.Any())
                {
                    folders.AddRange(subDirectory);
                }
            }
        }

        return folders;
    }
```

Function to validate if folder contains subfolders

```
private static bool IsDirectoryEmpty(string path)
{
        return !Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(path).Any();
}
```